# What do you use Luxury gemstones for?

Tags: slipways

Starting a new game, I got a *Gemstone Asteroids* modifier. I quickly found the a gemstone asteroid and managed to mine it.
But I can't figure out what they are good for?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, according to [Fandom](https://slipways.fandom.com/wiki/Technology), the luxury gemstone is mentioned under the **Manufactured Luxury**, where:

> Every Prosperous forgeworld produces two units of Luxury.
>
> Luxury: Accepted by any planet producing People. Planets receiving at least one Luxury get +2% Happiness .

Comment: Darn. I really wish I had taken a bigger screen shot. I'm sure I tried pawning the Luxuries off to the nearby planets, but it didn't do anything. Maybe none of them happened to be producing People?

Comment: Hmm either that or there's some specific requirement to unlock the "manufactured luxury" @DJPirtu